# how to run a simple node.js file using batch file

Tags: node.js, batch-file

I have one simple "Hello World" program in Node.js. I want to run this using batch file.

```js
var http=require("http");

http.createServer(function(request,response){
 response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
 response.end('Hello World!..\n');
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

I have used this batch file named 'new.bat'.

```
if not "%minimized%"=="" goto :minimized
set minimized=true
@echo off
start /min cmd /c "C:\Users\USER2\Desktop\webchat\server.js"
goto :EOF
:minimized
```

please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this code to create a batch file:

```
if not "%minimized%"=="" goto :minimized
set minimized=true
@echo off

cd "C:\app path"

start /min cmd /C "nodemon server.js"
goto :EOF
:minimized
```

to run node.js in background.

Instead of running your app like you are used to like
`node server.js`, you can use nodemon: `nodemon server.js`

The most simple way you can imagine for a node package:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Comment: ohh ok i will install it and check.. what is nodemon?

Comment: if you made any changes in node.js.you dont have to refresh again.nodemon will auto refresh the file

Comment: welcome @nagaraj i think you got idea that how to create batch file

Answer (score 3):

server.js

```js
var http=require("http");

http.createServer(function(request,response){
    response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    response.end('Hello World!..\n');
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

new.bat [image]

```
if not "%minimized%"=="" goto :minimized
set minimized=true
@echo off
cd "C:\Users\USER2\Desktop\webchat"

start /min cmd /C "nodemon server.js"
goto :EOF
:minimized
```

Run the application in cmd:
[image: run the application in cmd]
[image: after running the application in cmd the node.js command prompt will look like this.. the application running successfully]
[image: now you can see the output in browser by setting localhost and the port]