# Write a batch file to run a node.js file located in another directory

Tags: node.js, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

In Windows 10, I have created a scheduled task using **SCHTASKS** command to run a node.js file in every 10 minutes using a `.bat` file. I have used git bash to write that command.

Here is my SCHTASKS command:

```
schtasks //Create //sc minute //mo 10 //tn "Repeat_10Check" //tr \\runnode.bat
```

My `.bat` file is located in root directory i.e. **C:\Users\username**.

My `.bat` file's name is **runnode.bat**

I want to run **example.js** file which is located in **F:\Nodejs\project\subfolder** directory, using that `.bat` file by running the following command:

```
SCHTASKS //RUN //TN "Repeat_10Check"
```

Normally in git bash i would write following command to run a node.js file:

```
cd ../../../F/Nodejs/project/subfolder
node example.js
```

What should i write in **runnode.bat** to execute those command using the batch file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file will always be in that directory you could provide a static reference to it like so

```
SCHTASK /Create /SC MINUTE /MO 10 /TN “Check Every 10 Minutes” /TR F:\ Nodejs\project\subfolder\runnode.bat
```

And in the myJsScriptrun.bat you could just have it do node example.js

So what the above does is run the .bat file located in the same directory as example.js - this allows us to use node example.js - every 10 minutes.

If you can’t / don’t want to change the directory of runnode.bat you could just do within the runnode.bat

```
node F:\Nodejs\project\subfolder\example.js
```

Now if you are going to run this as user the above is fine.

Although you can specify parameters such as runasadministrator - Using the /RU tag.

I do suggest giving http://www.robvanderwoude.com/schtasksxp.php a read for further research

Comment: I have followed your suggestion. But when i am executing `SCHTASKS //RUN //TN "Repeat_10Check"` a pop up command prompt showed up and hide within a blink of an eye. What should i do now ? @Lucy

Comment: As I don’t have your available scripts. I did a quick search for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43650337/how-to-run-a-simple-node-js-file-using-batch-file/43650419 or if you Wonna update your original with both the  updated SCHTASKS as well as the updated bat and I can look further into it for you as mine worked perfectly.

Comment: I have found it. Change directory command is not same for Windows & Linux. That's why `.bat` file couldn't find correct folder. Thanks a lot @Lucy